# Do something if nth number

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to create a celery task that runs some background stuff if the column in the DB value is a 'fifth number'. I'm not sure what to call it, but

```
if the number is 5 -> Do something 
if the number is 10 -> Do something 
if the number is 15 -> Do something 
if the number is 20 -> Do something 
if the number is 25 -> Do something
```

and so on. The functions should only check if the current value is a 'fifth number' so the code only runs once. How would I go on about creating this kind of checker? I'd appreciate any kind of resource I can check out

Comment: `if number % 5 == 0` is that what you want?

Comment: you can write an `if` consition like `if(x%5==0): print("Carry out the necessary task")`

Comment: You're right guys. That was much simpler than I expected. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
i=5 #Your number    
if i%5==0:
    print('Hello') #Do Something
```

Comment: Wow that was much simpler than I thought. Oh wow, thank you so much! I can't accept the answer before 9 minutes has passed, but i'll do it once they have. :-)

Answer (score 2):

The way to check if the number is a multiple of 5 is by analyzing the module of the division by 5. The expression `number % 5 == 0` will return true if the number is a multiple of 5 (5, -10, 15, -25, etc., but also 0, so be on the lookout for that if 0 is not a "fifth number" as you called) but false for any other number.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that 0 also counts! It should not run at 0, so i'll implement some code for that!